# Force Ubuntu To Install Legacy?

Tags: uefi, window

So here is the issue I am having. My BIOS boot mode is set to Legacy+UEFI and my Windows 8.1 installed as Legacy, however, when I try to install Ubuntu, it attempts to install as UEFI and doesn't detect windows and can't install GRUB properly. So I was wondering if there was a way to force Ubuntu to install as Legacy or if I need to completely reinstall everything.

Also, this is a custom built computer. The motherboard is an MSI Z87-GD65 Gaming motherboard.

Comment: Also, this is a custom built computer. The motherboard is an MSI Z87-GD65 Gaming motherboard.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 4):

First, [verify that Windows is booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html#windows) Windows 8.1 booting in that mode is certainly plausible on a self-built computer, but you should be 100% certain of what you're dealing with.

Second, the simplest way to get Ubuntu to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode is to remove the EFI boot loaders from the Ubuntu boot medium. If you're booting from a USB flash drive, deleting the `EFI` directory tree on the flash drive should do the trick. There's also a Mac-specific version which, ironically, is BIOS-only, so you could download and use that.