# How to force Ubuntu to install in legacy mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, grub-legacy

In [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439326/force-ubuntu-to-install-legacy) question,the answer said that we can force Ubuntu to install in legacy mode by deleting the `EFI` directory tree on the flash drive.

But how can we do this?

I wanted to delete that from flash drive but there is no delete option!

I wanna install 2 Linux OS's in legacy mode,but Ubuntu don't let me do that!
When i choose Legacy mode in Bios,In the first of the installation ubuntu shows error!it says that i most install it in UEFI mode.

`ls` output from flash drive:

```
boot    dists  install   md5sum.txt  pool     README.diskdefines
casper  EFI    isolinux  pics        preseed  ubuntu
```

Note that my laptop has no CD-ROM.

Comment: did you set the EFI Firmware to allow Legacy boot mode? Note: secure boot usually has to be turned off to allow legacy boot.

Comment: Ubuntu will be installed in the mode that you booted your live system into. So if you boot your live system into BIOS mode alias CSM alias legacy mode, the installed system will be installed in legacy mode. Normally you select boot mode in the computer's UEFI/BIOS menus.

Comment: The previous comment is about *installing*, making an installed system. Is that what you want, or do you want to create a USB boot drive, that works in legacy mode? If you use the cloning method, clone with for example `mkusb` from the Ubuntu iso file to the USB flash drive, a 32-bit version will boot in legacy mode  and a 64-bit version will boot both in legacy mode and UEFI mode.

Comment: @ravery i forgot to turn off secure boot,let me try it.

Comment: @sudodus no it's not about creating bootable USB drive,i just couldn't install ubuntu in legacy mode beside kali-linux,should i install ubuntu first or kali? and i've already selected legacy mode from bios

Comment: Depends on which Linux you want to have as your main option. This one you should install last. saves you editing and updating grub :)

Comment: The distro that you install last will grab the bootloader and become the main option in grub. So I suggest that you install Ubuntu last to make it the main option ;-)

Comment: @ravery yes u were right,turning off the secure boot works, thanks

Comment: @sudodus i installed kali-ubuntu... i installed kali first,then ubuntu,but in both my touchpad doesn't work:-/

Comment: There is probably a missing driver for your touchpad in the versions of linux, that is used (in Ubuntu and Kali). *Tell us about your computer, at least brand name and model*, better if you can find the touchpad's brand name and model, and somebody might be able to tell you how to solve the problem. You can also *try live (without installing) another version of Ubuntu*, which has another linux kernel, which has other hardware drivers. So if you installed 17.10, you can try 16.04.1 and 16.04.3 LTS live. See this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865