# Force to install Ubuntu only in Legacy

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 20.10

I have Dell 5110n laptop that belongs to 2011 so it won't support **UEFI** at all. Now I just wanna know how can I:

1. Make bootable USB flash for JUST **Legacy** mode
2. Force **Ubuntu** to install only in **Legacy** mode

I want install **Ubuntu** dual boot with **Windows 10** (Version 1709 build 16299.461).

I read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439326/) and also deleted **EFI** directory but the Ubuntu still doesn't show Keyboard icon that shows it loaded in UEFI mode.

and if I don't make **`EFI`** partition it gives me the below error:
[image: Force Ubuntu to boot just in Legacy]

also when I make an **EFI** partition it will gives me this error at the end and will fail the installation process:

[image: Install Ubuntu Dell 5110n Legacy mode]

**P.S**: I know I should boot my USB in just Legacy mode because my Windows installed in Legacy mode too. But I don't know how should I do that. Either make bootable USB (with **Rufus** or **Universal USB installer**) or just force Ubuntu to boot in Legacy.
**P.S**: My bios doesn't have any "**Fast boot**" or "**Secure boot**" option or any way to boot in **UEFI**.

so can you please give me a hand?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for your replying but that picture wasn't mine. Would you please check the picture again? I just took and uploaded mine. I have two HDD. one Samsung SSD and another Hitachi HDD. So I'm sure I installed Win 10 in Legacy mode because when I juse "msinfo32" it gives me "Legacy".

Comment: Yes, that pic is a legacy dos disk. The Ubuntu ISO boots either way, depending upon how your machine's BIOS/UEFI settings are.  Unfortunately, each vendor may use different terminology for this.  CSM mode is compatibility or legacy, You might have a choice of prefering legacy over UEFI. Maybe all you have is Win7 vs. other. Setting the BIOS to boot legacy should be a lot easier than recreating the ISO without the UEFI bootloaders.

Comment: Rufus creates BIOS only or UEFI only flash drive installer. This is UEFI: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278772/unable-to-access-ubuntu-from-uefi You want BIOS and CSM mode. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off. This currently shows Rufus BIOS only screen. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#3-usb-selection Since mode installs are now to newer systems with UEFI, it may change in future.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tested with multiple version of Rufus randomly but none of them had only "Legacy" or only "Bios" item so I used latest version and so on...
[Rufus 2.10.973](https://imgur.com/fhvLjA0) - 
[Rufus 3.1.1320](https://imgur.com/8LKyBvQ) - 
as I told my Bios doesn't have any "Secure boot" or "Fast boot" to turn it off. so I can't turn them off. so do you know any other way to boot in LEGACY? or make a USB bootable just in LEGACY? Thanks in advance

Comment: when ubuntu ask you to reboot or to proceed with live-session. choose to proceed and the try do install grub on /dev/sda . `sudo grub-install /dev/sda' in live-session.  this was for me the only way, for bios mode.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping and sharing your information and experience. So you mean OS installation process failed just due to "grub-install" ? and all other process completed successfully? So if I install grub manually everything should works fine? Because I think the "grub-install" is not the last step and after that the OS should install another things and do some other steps. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Here is the solution for those have same problem like me:

The reason of getting error was having two HDD. The old HDD, and new one is SSD. So the Bootloader was stored on old HDD meanwhile the **`Ubuntu`** installed on SSD and when I was trying to fix grub, it was trying to fix old HDD. So my friend fixed Bootloader with **`EasyBCD`** app and then problem solved because he set Bootloader to loading from SSD.

Hope this help many people.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on a pre-uefi GA-EX58-UD4P mb with award bios. I get the fatal error installing ubuntu 20.04 on a new SSD.  A live boot-repair usb also fails to install boot loader due to the session having booted in "compatibility" mode.
I did find a work around by shutting down after a "fatal error" install, then plugging in and booted an old ubuntu hdd. Then did "sudo update-grub". Shut down + unplugged the old hdd. Booted the new install and the link to it appeared in the grub bootloader screen.
I suspect using a live usb session to mount the disk the failed install is located on then using "sudo update-grub" might have worked too.